# Rotating 3D coordinates to 2D plane

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d, rotations

I'm trying to solve this problem but I'm stuck;

I have 2 coordinates, in 3D, say $C_1 = (x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $C_2 = (x_2,y_2,z_2)$.
Now I'd like to transpose these to a 2-dimensional plane, but instead of just saying $z_1=z_2=0$. I'd like to keep the distance and relation between these two coordinates.

So, I figured for that I should transpose the coordinates, such that $C_1$ is at $(0,0,0)$, and $C_2 = (x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1, z_2-z_2-z_1)$, and then rotate with a rotation matrix $R$.

But can someone help me with how to find the right rotation matrix if I want the lenght on the x-axis?

Comment: When you say "distance and relation" can you clarify what that means?  A simple approach is to take the line the two points are on and translate it onto your plane...

Comment: Yes that is what i like to do, translate the line between the two points and translate it onto my plane. I want to find the translation matrix that translates the two coordinates such that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are 0, but i dont know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the vectors be denoted by $v_1$ and $v_2$ (my preference :)).

1. Get the cross product of the two: $c = v_1 \times v_2$
   $c$ is orthogonal to both $v_1$ and $v_2$.
2. Get the angle between $c$ and $k=(0,0,1)$:
   $$
   \cos\theta = \frac{c\cdot k}{|c|}
   $$
3. Rotate both vectors about $a = c \times k$ by $\theta$ using [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)
   You have to normalize $a$ to get a unit vector before applying it to the formula: $a' = a/|a|$.

The pair of resulting vectors is one instance of possible rotations and both are perpendicular to $k$ ($z$-axis).

The rotation matrix can be obtained from [Rotation matrix from axis and angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)

Comment: Thanks! I found the correct solution to my problem! Didn't knew about the Rodrigues rotation, but it's a very handy formula! Unfortunately i cant upvote you yet..

Comment: @Pickels I've got curious about your approach :) You can update the post to show your solution if you have time.

Comment: I used your answer! Going through your steps gave me the correct solution! :)

Comment: @Pickels Oh, I see. I thought you found your own approach.